# Use of Context in Explicit Intents

Tags: android

What is the difference between starting ActivityB from ActivityA using

```
1. startActivity(this, ActivityB.class);
```

versus

```
2. startActivity(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
```

I typically see 1. used more often in examples, but I haven't come across a reason for why this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference to Activity as a Context (`this`) might become obsolete if your Activity goes through configuration changes, like rotation, and is destroyed and created again. Context recieved by `getApplicationContext()`, however, persists through lifetime of the process.

However, It seems to me it only is an issue when you bind Activity to Service or other similar scenario, so it's safe to use `this` when you use it in intent to start another Activity.

Comment: So, if I understand your response correctly, when providing a Context to start Activity B from Activity A, there is no absolutely no advantage or disadvantage in using (this) over (getApplicationContext())?

Comment: as far as I know - there is no difference.

Comment: The application context don't change until your app is terminated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. According source code of [Intent](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/content/Intent.java?av=f#3003) and [ComponentName](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/content/ComponentName.java#74) - only thing, that used form context - is getting package name by `context.getPackageName()`. Package name is the same for `Activity.this` and `Activity.getApplicationContext()`, so there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are actually asking about the difference between

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityB.class));
```

and

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class));
```

There is no difference. Android needs the ComponentName (package name and class). The context is used to determine the package name.